# Page does not display on production server

Tags: php, localhost, server

Pages display correctly when I am in localhost or on the internal server to my office but when I put the site on the server production some pages do not display any more. Where from what is that can come? Is that come from the configuration of the server?

Comment: This wholly depends on what you're trying to do. Are there any errors being reported on your production server? Is there a PHP version mismatch between the servers?  You should add more detail to your question.

Comment: This issue would need more code examples or some information from the Error logs. Please provide more details, errors, or examples.

Comment: Thanks for your answers, I tried something stupid, I copied the contents of the file concerned later I erased the file, then I created a new file and to copy inside and it works, I know that does not come from my code but I understand nothing there.

Comment: Start by turning your error reporting on - `ini_set('display_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);` (*at the top of your script*). We'd need to also see your code. I presume it's a 500 error.